# How to display array byte in C#?

Tags: c#

I use C# Windows Form. I seem need convert to string. How I can do this?

```
byte[] data = new byte[256];
```

Comment: try string result = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data);

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Babaev what do you mean? Do you want to display the hexadecimal values or convert UTF/ASCII data to a string?

Comment: Please give an example of the input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using System.Text and this should work:

```
string mystr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

Comment: That would produce meaningful results only if the original data was a UTF8 string

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes but I don't have enough reputation to ask what Encoding he was using but usually it's UTF8 or ASCII. Thanks for specifying that though.

Comment: Why do you assume it's text data in the first place?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos He's trying to convert it to a string...

Comment: `I seem need convert to string`